# How to write "FUST" fonts upright in the environment of Theorem but not Italic font?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

How to write "FUST" fonts upright in the environment of Theorem but not Italic font? Thanks!

[image]

```
\begin{theorem}
Let $G$ be an infinite connected graph and let  $\{G_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be an exhaustion of $G$ as above. Then the weak limits 
\[\textbf{FUSF}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \textbf{UST}_{G_n}.
\]
and 
\[\textbf{WUSF}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \textbf{UST}_{G^*_n}.
\]
exists and do not depend on the exhaustion $\{G_n\}_{n\ge 1}$.
\end{theorem}
```

Comment: Don't use `\text...` command for maths: Use `\mathbf{FUSF}` to get boldface or use `\mathsf{FUSF}` to get sans serif as in the screenshot. If you type FUSF, WUSF and UST often, define a command for it (`\newcommand*{\fusf}{\mathbf{FUSF}}`) so that you can easily change the output with one modification of a single line.

Comment: @moewe Thanks! If I did not use `\text`. How about general font without boldface in the Theorem environment?

Comment: The code has `\textbf`. Since it's the same for `\textit`, `\textsf` I wrote `\text...` as a catch-all for those `\text<two letters>` commands in my comment above. I'm sorry I don't understand the second part of your comment.

Comment: @moewe I mean if I want to write text font in Theorem environment without boldface, how to do that? Because if I write `\text{...}` in Theorem environment, it will be Italic font but not upright.

Comment: Are you talking about the maths bit of the theorem (e.g. the bit in between `\[...\]` in your example, where you actually have a FUSF)? If so, the answer is not to use a command whose name starts with `\text...`. In math mode you need to use commands like `\mathbf`, `\mathrm` and `\mathsf` as mentioned in my first comment. If you are talking about the text part of the theorem, there is currently no bold face in your example, so I don't understand what exactly you are trying to do. ...

Comment: ... BTW it is possible that the code shown so far produces some unusual output in your setting (for example if your preamble does weird things), I'm working under the assumption that you have a standard preamble like https://gist.github.com/moewew/ce546f8a5f97193687498884a5a76bb0. If you want help that is guaranteed to work in your setting, you need to share a small, yet compilable example document that reproduces your maths settings (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)

Comment: No, not the math part `\[\]` but the text part above `\[\]` in the Theorem environment. Does there any way if I want to write `FUST' upright in the text part.

Comment: Or if you do want to switch to text mode within math mode, use `\textup` or `\textnormal`, rather than `\text`.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks! It works.

Comment: Then why does the example code not show an instance of FUSF in the text? That would have made it much clearer what was wanted. If FUSF is a mathematical object I think it could be argued that it should be written in math mode (just like the graph G is in math mode), so then you'd use `$\mathbf{FUSF}$`. If it is text, it should normally follow the formatting of the surrounding text, so italics would be appropriate, but if you insist on not having them `\textup{\textbf{FUSF}}` or `\textnormal{\textbf{FUSF}}` should work.

Answer (score 1):

As you’ve noticed, the `\text` command inherits the formatting of the surrounding text, including italic style.

Alternatives include `\textup` to use the upright style of the text font, `\mathrm` for upright text in math mode, or `\mathsf` for sans-serif text.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your own commands for those object and the definition should not rely on `\textZZ` commands (where `ZZ` can be nothing or `bf` or `sf` and so on).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newcommand{\herminame}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}
\newcommand{\FUSF}{\herminame{FUSF}}
\newcommand{\WUSF}{\herminame{WUSF}}
\newcommand{\UST}{\herminame{UST}}

\begin{document}

% just to get section 4 and theorem 14
\setcounter{section}{4}
\setcounter{theorem}{13}

\begin{theorem}[Pemantle 1991]
Let $G$ be an infinite connected graph and let  $\{G_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be 
an exhaustion of $G$ as above. Then the weak limits 
\[
\FUSF=\lim_{n\to \infty} \UST_{G_n}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\WUSF=\lim_{n\to \infty} \UST_{G^*_n}
\]
exist and do not depend on the exhaustion $\{G_n\}_{n\ge 1}$.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

I set the limits on one line to save space but also to show that `\text` inherits the font attributes of the text surrounding the math formula; `\textbf` would just *add* the boldface attribute, but in this case the italic attribute would be preserved.

[image]

The image above matches the one you posted that uses `\mathsf`, but you can just modify the definition of `\herminame` to suit your preference. For instance, if you prefer boldface to sans serif, you can simply change one line, namely

```
\newcommand{\herminame}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
```

to get

[image]